# How to see stack trace of test code of Go program?

Tags: debugging, testing, go

I use Go's native test facility (`go test`) to write a test. But when the test fails due to a bug in test code, I really can't debug it due to lack of stack trace or any other contextual informations.

And even, the test code needs one contextual object `t`, so it is not simple work running the test code in normal mode.

What is the best practice to debug test code?

Comment: You might consider [GoConvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey) for easy access to stack traces when your code panics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `t.Log()` to log information about the test case -- go will show that output if the test case fails or if you run `go test -v`

You can also assert certain state within the test using panics -- if a test panics, you will see the trace in your console.

Answer (score 9):

You can log stack trace this way

```
t.Log(string(debug.Stack()))
```

Documentation is here https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#Stack

It is better than `PrintStack` because it doesn't interfere with regular test logs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you'd want to check in code with this in it, but for one-off debugging, PrintStack might help. http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack

Comment: No this doesn't work. Because in test mode, it doesn't show the regular logs. I had to use `fmt` package to print something.